# Change of variation under rigid coordinate transformation

Tags: coordinate-systems, calculus-of-variations, euler-lagrange-equation, rigid-transformation

Suppose I have a functional 
$$
E=\int F(y_{1,1},..y_{1,n},y_{2,1}\ldots,y_{n,n})d\boldsymbol{x}\,,
$$
 where $\boldsymbol{y}:\mathbb{R}^{n}\to\mathbb{R}^{n},\,\boldsymbol{y}(\boldsymbol{x})=\left(y_{1}(x_{1},...x_{n}),...,y_{n}(x_{1},...x_{n})\right)$,
and $y_{1,1},...,y_{n,n}$ are partial derivatives, i.e. $y_{i,j}=\dfrac{dy_{i}}{dx_{i}}$.

How the **variation** of the functional $\dfrac{\delta E(\boldsymbol{y})}{\delta(\boldsymbol{y})}$
is changed under a rigid coordinates transformation (of both the domain and the image.) 
$$
\left(x_{1},...,x_{n}\right)^{T}=V\left(v_{1},...,v_{n}\right)^{T};\,\left(y_{1},...,y_{n}\right)^{T}=U\left(u_{1},...,u_{n}\right)^{T},
$$

where $U,V$ are orthogonal $n\times n$ matrices.

In other words, given $\dfrac{\delta E(\boldsymbol{y(x)})}{\delta(\boldsymbol{y(x)})}$
what would be the expression for $\dfrac{\delta E(\boldsymbol{u(v)})}{\delta(\boldsymbol{u(v)})}$?

Any comments would be appreciated!

Comment: P.S.  To be sure that there is no ambiguity in my question;
by "variation'' I mean the one that follows from the Euler Lagrange
equation for $E$  that depends on partial derivatives of $n$-functions
of $n$-variables i.e.,
$$
\dfrac{\delta E(\boldsymbol{y(x)})}{\delta(\boldsymbol{y(x)})}=\left(\underset{i=1}{\overset{n}{\sum}}\dfrac{\partial}{\partial x_{i}}\dfrac{\partial F}{\partial y_{1,i}},\ldots,\underset{i=1}{\overset{n}{\sum}}\dfrac{\partial}{\partial x_{i}}\dfrac{\partial F}{\partial y_{n,i}}\right)^{T}.
$$